# Embed partial templates with Backbone / Marionette / Underscore templates

Tags: templates, backbone.js, underscore.js, marionette

In Marionette with Underscore templates, is it possible to 'include' one template file into another template file - so that common markup can be shared across multiple templates?

We use requireJS to load the .tpl files as and when - and then assign a tpl file to a Marionette view;

```
  View.MyView = Marionette.ItemView.extend({
        template: 'parent_template.tpl'
  });
```

Where 'parent_template.tpl' contains something like.

```
  <h1>A Parent View</h1>
  <button class='btn-one'>One</button> 
  <button class='btn-two'>Two</button>
  <button class='btn-three'>three</button>
```

What I would like to do is extract say the buttons to a common tpl, that other tpl's could use, something like...

Where 'parent_template.tpl' contains something like.

```
  <h1>A Parent View</h1>
   {{child_template.tpl}}
```

And 'child_template.tpl' contains something like.

```
  <button class='btn-one'>One</button> 
  <button class='btn-two'>Two</button>
  <button class='btn-three'>three</button>
```

And then lots of other templates could pull in the shared template.

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Marionette, but Underscore templates are designed to be super-simple and not include any logic at all (including an "embedding" mechanism).  If you used a more advanced templating system like say Handlebars, you could roll your own include "helper" or use a pre-built one like this https://www.npmjs.org/package/handlebars-helper-include.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way that I solved this was with templateHelpers.

Load the partial templates as per usual with require JS.
Then pass a reference to the child template into the parent template via the templateHelper;

```
define(['tpl!parent.tpl', 'tpl!child.tpl'], function (ParentTemplate, ChildTemplate) {

   View.MyView = Marionette.View.extend({
      template: ParentTemplate,
      templateHelpers: function() {
        return {
          childTpl: ChildTemplate
        }
      }
    });
}
```

The parent template includes the child via the helper

```
<h1>parent template</h1>
<%= childTpl(obj) %>
```

The child can access the data if you pass 'obj' - the template model

```
<h2>this is the child, that can access the parent data <%= title %></h2>
```

Answer (score 1):

For me it smells odd including template in template.
You can instead use Mariontte.LayoutView with subview:

buttons subview :

```
Buttons = Marionette.ItemView.extend({
         template: 'child_template.tpl'
});
```

layout :

```
MyView = Marionette.LayoutView.extend({
         template: 'parent_template.tpl',
         region : {
              buttonRegion : '.myButtonsRegion'
         },
         onShow : function(){
              var buttons = new Buttons();
              this.buttonRegion.show(buttons);
         }
});
```

and then parent_template.tpl :

```
<h1>A Parent View</h1>
<div class="myButtonsRegion"></div>
```